# Depth-fighting solution using custom depth testing

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-testing, zbuffer

The core of my problem is that I have troubles with depth-fighting in pure OpenGL. 
I have two identical geometries, but one is simpler than the other. 
That forms a set of perfectly coplanar polygons, and I want to display the complex geometry on top of the simpler geometry.

Unsurprisingly, it leads me to depth-fighting when I draw sequentially the two sets of triangles using the OpenGL depth buffer. At the moment, I've patched it using `glPolygonOffset` but this solution is not suitable for me (I want the polygons the be exactly coplanar).

My idea is to temporary use a custom depth test when drawing the second set of triangles. I would like to save the depth of the fragments during the rendering of the first set. Next, I would use `glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS)` to disable the depth buffer (but still writing in it). When rendering the second set, I would discard fragments that have a greater z than the memory I just created, but with a certain allowance (at least one time the precision of the Z-buffer at the specific z, I guess). Then I would reset depth function to `GL_LEQUAL`.

Actually, I just want to force a certain allowance for the depth test.

Is it a possible approach ?
The problem is that I have no idea how to pass information (custom depth buffer) from one program to another.

Thanks

PS : I also looked into Frame Buffer Objects and Deferred Rendering because apparently it allows passing information via a 'G-buffer', but once I write:

```
unsigned int gBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &gBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);
```

My window goes black... Sorry if things are obvious I'm not familiar yet with OpenGL

Comment: How would your depth approach be different from using `glPolygonOffset`? In the end, I don't think what you want is possible since while drawing the second object you'd have to read and write to the depth-buffer at the same time which is not easily possible.

Comment: *"`glPolygonOffset` but this solution is not suitable for me (I want the polygons the be exactly coplanar)."*  - `glPolygonOffset` only changes the depth value and doesn't gain any distortion in the projection to the viewport.

Comment: If I understood correctly ```glPolygonOffset```, it basically move the vertices to the camera. I will be drawing several layers of objects (I don't know excalty what for the moment) on top of the second object, that's why I would like not to stack the offsets.

Comment: "you'd have to read and write to the depth-buffer at the same time which is not easily possible" That's why I would like to keep in memory the zbuffer previously computed, if possible.

Comment: @Kiord `glPolygonOffset` does not *"move the vertices"*, it adds an offset to the depth value, before it is compared to the value in the depth buffer, that is something completely different.

Comment: @Kiord: Keeping the old depth-buffer in memory wouldn't help since you would then not depth-test fragments of the second pass against each other.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh ok. I see I'm trying to do the exact same thing with my custom zbuffer then. lol.

Comment: @Kiord You can't do this in general, because `glPolygonOffset` adds an offset which depends on basic machine units, on the format (bits) of the depth buffer. All you can do is to implement a in shader solution for one know depth buffer format, which at the end is slower than `glPolygonOffset`.

Comment: It seems that the value written in the zbuffer is the shifted value... https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113795/little-question-about-glpolygonoffset .

Comment: @Kord Yes of course.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Well, I need to stack several layers of polygons (I don't know how many, that's the point). That means I need to call ```glPolygonOffset``` each time with a greater offset. At some point, I will be unable to draw a polygon I front of my main mesh because the offset will be too high, right ? That's why I was planning to manually do the depth test using a custom depth-buffer.

Comment: @Kiord Disable the depth test and draw the polygons in layered order, then you don't need any depth offset at all.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Unfortunately, my main mesh can hide itself. Disabling the depth test will show some polygons that shouldn't be visible.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Absolutely. But if there is a second layer triangle the other side (non visible side) of the mesh, it shouldn't appear on screen. Disabling the depth-test will make it visible, right ?

Comment: @Kiord So you've to keep the depth buffer as it is after the "main" object. Enable depth test, but set [`glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthMask.xhtml) after the main object and draw in layered order.

Comment: @Rabbid76 LOL I just realized I can do that. Thank you ! Problem solved ;)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Just a last point, I know that zbuffer precision is decreasing when moving toward z axis... Does ```glPolygonOffset``` take that in consideration ? I mean, does the offset depends of the distance ? I just need to be sure that it will work at any distance

Comment: @Kiord The offset is linear it is the minimum amount which is necessary to gain a difference in depth buffer, based on the format of the buffer. In other words, the minimum depth offset ensures that there is difference of 1 "bit".

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rabbid76 said, I can simply disable depth writing using `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`.
Now, I can draw several layers of coplanar polygons using the same offset.
Solved.